# SQL Server And operator with ON

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am having a query in which I am using left outer join to fetch records from two tables.

Now, query is something like this :

```
SELECT Table1.Id, Table1.Name, Table2.DeviceId
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Table1Id AND Table2.DeviceId=4
WHERE Table1.Name LIKE 'xxxxxx' AND Table1.IsDeleted=0
```

And it is giving me the desired result.

But when I use

```
SELECT Table1.Id, Table1.Name, Table2.DeviceId 
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Table1Id  
WHERE Table1.Name LIKE 'xxxxxx' AND Table1.IsDeleted=0 AND Table2.DeviceId=4
```

it is not giving the desired result.

Now, I am not getting what is difference between AND operator in ON statement and in WHERE Clause?

Can anybody explain?

Thanks..

Comment: what are the wrong results?

Comment: It changes the join predicate. Logically, this is applied before the `WHERE` clause. When you put `AND Table2.DeviceId = 4` in the `WHERE` clause you basically turn the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @Szymon I am not getting desired records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It is very important to understand that, with outer joins, the ON and WHERE clauses play very different roles, and therefore, they aren’t interchangeable. The WHERE clause still plays a simple filtering role—namely, it keeps true cases and discards false and unknown cases. Use something like this and use predicates in where clause. However, the ON clause doesn’t play a simple filtering role; rather, it’s more a matching role. In other words, a row in the preserved side will be returned whether the ON predicate finds a match for it or not. So the ON predicate only determines which rows from the nonpreserved side get matched to rows from the preserved side—not whether to return the rows from the preserved side." **Exam 70-461: Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012